# Which tool to use for drawing large scatterplots

Tags: dataset, graph

For drawing Scatter plots of >100K points, Excel 2007/10 hangs under repeated refresh.

What is a better tools for such tasks. I have 4 GB ram etc on this machine.

Comment: Do you really need to plot all 100K points? I expect many (most?) will overlap, so plotting the overlaps is unnecessary. Even if they don't overlap, you won't even have enough pixels on a standard screen to display them all. Can you pre-filter the data to reduce the amount plotted?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I guess I want to include overlaps as well, since it's kind of a big-picture chart with trendlines for action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of a learning curve, you could use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) - it's free and excellent.

Answer (score 1):

[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) to the rescue.